# Use Theme.AppCompat in a xamarin.android app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I'm trying to make an Android app through Xamarin. I work on Windows 10 with VS2015.

I have to implement a side bar menu. After some research I found a solution to do it : use a DrawerLayout and others tools. That's why I use Theme.AppCompat in my application.

But when I'm trying to make a style which herits from Theme.Appcompat.light.NoActionBar, I got compile issue. The message is :

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

I've added Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat references to my project as bellow :

[Project References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3CB.png)

Edit: I also tried to add them by xamarin Component and nuget package manager.

But nothing compile.

Here is the code which produce this error:

```
<resources>
  <style name="DailyCoin.HomeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#219653</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyDrawerArrowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

minSdkVersion is 17 and compile using version is 23

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution.
My problem was that xamarin was corrupted and the component adding module had some troubles when i added components. So i removed all references/components i've added to my projet, reinstalled xamarin.

Just for people impatient like me:
Then i had a new issue : "Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r28.zip" because when generated the solution, it took a lot of time and i stoped this.
The solution was to delete all zips in "%localappdata%/xamarin/zips" and wait for the generation.

Thank for your help !

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Check this out (its working for me): [Navigation Drawer using material design](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/01/navigation-drawer-using-material-design.html)

Comment: It doesn't work, but i'm going to check your link ! Thank's

Comment: I've already checked your link, it's one of the tutorials i've followed.
But after tried to compile his source code available on github, first it didn't compile, then i noted that's he gets references inside his project.
When i tried to add components, they were just placed in components folder without references added. Then i tried to add reference myself and many things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out `@android:style/` so just:

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I tried your code in a new Android project and it compiled. Make sure to use just `Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle` as well.